# wordpress - if is_bbPress() register jquery

Tags: php, wordpress

i use this code to deregister jquery from wp_head():

```
<?php if ( !is_admin() ) wp_deregister_script('jquery'); wp_head(); ?>
```

i want jquery just added when user on bbpress page, but it's not working:

```
<?php
    if (is_bbPress()) (wp_register_script('jquery'); wp_head();}
    else (!is_admin()) (wp_deregister_script('jquery'); wp_head();}
?>
```

can somebody help me fix this please

Comment: Use wp_enqueue_script() function.

Comment: i get syntax error not working

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to enqueue scripts and styles is to use `wp_enqueue_script`:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

So, for example:

```
function my_enqueue_script() {
    if ( is_bbPress() ) {

        // The name used as a handle for the script
        $handle = 'script-name';

        // The url to the script
        $src = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js';

        // Array of the handles of all the registered scripts that must be loaded before this script
        $deps = array(); 

        // The version number of the script (if it has one)
        $ver = '1.0.0';

        // Should the script be placed in the document footer or the head?
        $in_footer = true;

        wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_script' );
```

Comment: i add this php codes into my function.php but js file is not included

Comment: It's an example of how you should enqueue the script. It isn't a working example.